# Overriding PSPDFKit email tableView to add my own options

Tags: objective-c, pspdfkit

I'm trying to extend the tableView's 'Send via email' options with some of my own. How can/should I go about extending the tableView that's displayed when you tap on the email icon at the top bar? Is that even possible? Or should I try to delegate the email button's buttonTapped action and create my own TableView from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

[PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com/) author here. (A PDF SDK for iOS and Android)

It's probably best to create your own table view if you want to fully customize this, and use `PSPDFProcessor` internally - that way you're most flexible. The share sheet have options (e.g. [mailSharingOptions](https://pspdfkit.com/api/ios/Classes/PSPDFConfiguration.html#//api/name/mailSharingOptions)) to disable parts, but if you need full customization all the underlying API calls are exposed as well for even further flexibility.